# getAttribute by TagName - JS

Tags: javascript, dom, getattribute

My specific situation is that I'm trying to remove/make inactive a link element from the DOM (I have no control over it being generated). The way that I plan to do this is through replacing the 'href' attribute with a nonsense value - the reason I've chosen to do it this way rather than simply using `disable = true` is so that the function can be reused on other occasions to change other attributes.

The problem I'm having is with `.getAttribute` where it returns the error "TypeError: elemArr.hasAttribute is not a function".

```
function removeLink(elem, att, value, replacement) {
    var elemArr = document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
    for (var i = 0; i < elemArr.length; i++) {
        var workingAtt = elemArr.hasAttribute(att);
        if (workingAtt.value === filePath) {
            elemArr[i].setAttribute(att, replacement);
        }
    }
}
removeLink("link", "href", "filePath", "#");
```

Any help with why this error is getting thrown is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can also try the display property http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on in there is that elemArr is an array, and arrays don't have a hasAttribute method. Rewrite your code as

```
function removeLink(elem, att, value, replacement) {
  var elemArr = document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
  for (var i = 0; i < elemArr.length; i++) {
    //this line here wasn't referring to a specific node but the array
    var workingAtt = elemArr[i].hasAttribute(att);
    if (workingAtt && elemArr[i].getAttribute(att) === value) {
      elemArr[i].setAttribute(att, replacement);
    }
  }
}
removeLink("link", "href", "filePath", "#");
```

And it will work.

A more succint approach would be something like this:

```
function removeLink(elem, att, value, replacement){
  var selector = elem + '['+ att +'="'+ value +'"]';
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function(node){
    node.setAttribute(att, replacement);
  });
}
```

It does basically the same thing, but is quite a bit shorter and more explicit.

Comment: hasAttribute returns a boolean. You can't call `<boolean>.value`.

Comment: I somehow missed that too! Updating asap

Answer (score 1):

`.hasAttribute()` returns a boolean `true` or `false`. Therefore, `workingAtt` will either equal `true` or `false`. Boolean values are not HTMLElements, therefore they do not have `value` attributes. That's why there's an error.

It looks like you're trying to do something like `select elements where there is a href attribute`.

If so, you can just filter them:

```
var myElements = [];

[].filter.call(elemArr, function(el) {
    if(el.hasAttribute(att)) {
        myElements.push(el);
    }
});

// then, do something with myElements
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code:

1. `elemArr.hasAttribute` instead of `elemArr[i].hasAttribute`.
2. `var workingAtt = elemArr.hasAttribute(att);` — here, `workingAtt` will be a boolean value, `workingAtt.value` is non-existent. You should use `elemArr[i].getAttribute(att)` and later use `workingAtt`, NOT `workingAtt.value` (it will be non-existent again!).
3. `if (workingAtt.value === filePath)` you're comparing to `filePath` while you should most definitely compare to `value` that you pass in the function.